# Force string quoting, while saving flow style

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have data, that looks somewhat like this

```py
data = {"a": {"a": "0.1.2", "b": "0.2.3"}, "c": 3}
```

and I want it to create a YAML document, that should look like this

```yaml
a: {a: "0.1.2", b: "0.2.3"}
c: 3
```

so, by default we will have

```py
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = {"a": {"a": "0.1.2", "b": "0.2.3"}, "c": 3}
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives us this

```yaml
a:
  a: 0.1.2
  b: 0.2.3
c: 3
```

but I need the dict to be inline and the strings to be quoted.
For inline dict I can use

```py
yaml.default_flow_style = None
```

almost there

```yaml
a: {a: 0.1.2, b: 0.2.3}
c: 3
```

and for strings

```py
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import SingleQuotedScalarString as dq
```

(I could also use `yaml.default_style = '"'` but it also quotes the keys and doesn't help with the flow)

the thing is double quotes somehow break the flow:

```py
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.default_flow_style = None
data = {"a": {"a": dq("0.1.2"), "b": dq("0.2.3")}, "c": 3}
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

gives me this back

```yaml
a:
  a: "0.1.2"
  b: "0.2.3"
c: 3
```

How can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to do in these kind of cases is see if `ruamel.yaml` can round-trip the required
output:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
a: {a: "0.1.2", b: "0.2.3"}
c: 3
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives exactly your input:

```
a: {a: "0.1.2", b: "0.2.3"}
c: 3
```

If you do:

```
yaml.default_flow_style = None
```

essentially all sequences and mappings that only contain scalars (as elements resp. keys and values) are
dumped in flow style. But since you wrap the strings that you want
quoted in your output, the dump process no longer sees those as scalars and that causes the block-style
to reappear.

If you insert `print(type(data['a']))` in the program above, you'll see that the mapping
is loaded in a `CommentedMap` and that can be coerced to be output as flow style:

```
DQ = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString
CM = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap 

cm = CM({"a": DQ("0.1.2"), "b": DQ("0.2.3")})
cm.fa.set_flow_style()
data = {"a": cm , "c": 3}
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
a: {a: "0.1.2", b: "0.2.3"}
c: 3
```

- I am not entirely sure how you could get double quotes using:

  ```
  from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import SingleQuotedScalarString as dq
  ```

  so that is why I used DoubleQuotedScalarString.
- there is no need to set  `yaml.default_flow_style = None`

Comment: It worked! Thank you